# Laravel Mail::Send works on local apache but complains about mime on nginx

Tags: email, nginx, laravel-5.3, swiftmailer

I have installed a laravel package for user verification

https://github.com/jrean/laravel-user-verification

Register Controller needs to be changed to work like below.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    $user = $this->create($request->all());
    $this->guard()->login($user);

    UserVerification::generate($user);
    UserVerification::send($user, 'Verification Mail from example.com');
    return redirect()->intended('/home');
}
```

Used mailgun to send mails.It worked fine on local apache. sent mails successfully to gmail and others.

Installed on nginx production(ubuntu 16.04 VPS ). It throws following error.

```
FatalThrowableError in SimpleMessage.php line 33:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::__construct() must 
be an instance of Swift_Mime_HeaderSet, none given, called in /var/www/example.com/
html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Message.php on line 48
```

To check if it is a package problem I have also done the following which works on local apache but throws the same error on nginx.

```
Route::get('/mailsend', function() {

$data = [
    'title' => 'hello user',
    'content' => 'Thanks for joining us'
];

Mail::send('mails.test', $data , function($message) {

    $message->to('example@gmail.com','example')->subject('Testing from example');
});

});
```

The code as shown in error /Swift/Message.php in line 48 as follows

```
 call_user_func_array(
    array($this, 'Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::__construct'),
    Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()
        ->createDependenciesFor('mime.message')
    );
```

Could not figure out the problem with nginx. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncomment line: extension=php_openssl.dll on **php.ini**

and check this https://laravel.io/forum/05-13-2014-smtp-mail-not-working-in-live-server

Comment: My server is a ubuntu server. dll's does not have any power over here. I am guessing it be more on nginx passing $headers to SimpleMessage.php.

Comment: sorry my mistake but you should be interested in this php_openssl. Visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/323005/php-openssl-extension-has-a-package